# What does よく mean in よく長時間働かせる?

Tags: adverbs, causation

Today I saw this sentence from [this page](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass):

> その部長は、よく長時間働かせる。

After chopping the sentence up, I found out that it means something around the lines of:

> That manager makes people work for very long periods of time.

But I could not understand why よく is there. So I scrolled down to look at the English translation, but that said nothing about why よく is here.

From my knowledge, よく is the adverb form of 良い (いい), which means "good".

But it does not make sense to use "well" or anything like that to describe the action of making people work for a long time! Who wants to work for long hours! How is it "good"?

Why exactly is よく used here? Is it something related to the causative form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should note that the adverb [*よく*](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F) has many meanings that include

> often, frequently.

It doesn't always mean

> nicely, well, skillfully, etc.

It all depends on context.

Comment: does that mean 良い has those meanings as well? i.e. often, frequent...

Comment: @Sweeper 良い  doesn't have a connotation related with "often" or "frequently". However, the meaning of よく is kind of derived from the meaning of the adjective. For example, if someone does something well, it could mean he does it often, frequently.

Answer (score 2):

it means "That manager **often** makes people work for very long periods of time"
よく in this sentence means "often"